# Maximum sum in array given constraints

Tags: java, arrays

## Problem Statement:

Given an array of positive integers, return the maximum sum.

*There is only one limitation*: if you pick two consecutive elements, you are not allowed to add any subsequent one to your total, and your sum is the amount accumulated up to that point. Your goal is to maximise your sum.

### Example 1:

**Input**: [1, 4, 2, 10]

**Output**: 14

### Example 2:

**Input**: [1, 4, 5, 3]

**Output**: 9

## My solution:

```java
  public static int solution(int[] boxes) {
    if(boxes.length == 0) {
      return 0; 
    }
    int tempMax = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      tempMax += boxes[i];
    }
    
    int max = tempMax;
    
    for(int i = 1; i < boxes.length - 1; i++) {
      int sub = tempMax - boxes[i - 1];
      tempMax = sub + boxes[i + 1];
      
      if(max < tempMax) {
        max = tempMax;
      }
    }
    
    return max;
  }
```

I keep failing on the first test case. I have tried a DP solution but that yielded the same results? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I ran it and it fails on the first rather than the second (i.e. example 1 produces 12 rather than 14 but example 2 produces 9).  In either case, I suggest that you run a debugger and/or add print statements to see if the program is doing what you think its doing.  My guess is that it is not.  Note, you only appear to be looking at consecutive boxes but the solution to example 1 involves non-consecutive boxes.  There appears to be a hidden rule that you cannot go backwards in the array to add a box.

Comment: "_Your total prize is the sum of all the boxes that you choose to include. There is only one limitation to the game: if you pick two consecutive boxes, you are not allowed to add any subsequent one to your total, and your prize is the amount accumulated up to that point. Your goal is to maximise your winnings._" - this doesn't match the title which is confusing me. Is the goal to sum all values without adding two consecutive indexes, the greatest sum of any two consecutive indexes, or the sum of the two greatest values in the array?

Comment: Fix that title.

Comment: From your description, in example 1 you can get 4+10+2, and in example 2, 4+3+5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are three different possibilities when considering whether or not to add a particular box to the score, I'd use recursion to keep things simple when exploring all the branches (Plus working from the end and memoizing those scores to better handle huge inputs):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Demo {

    /** 
     * Find the maximum possible score of the given boxes
     *
     * @param boxes The boxes
     * @param i the index of the current box we're considering adding
     * to the score.
     * @param score the current score without the current box
     * @param cache already computed maximum scores starting with the
     * Nth box, or -1 if not already found.
     * @return the maximum possible score
     */
    private static int solve(int[] boxes, int i, int score, int[] cache) {
        if (i >= boxes.length) {
            // No more boxes to consider
            return score;
        } else if (cache[i] > -1) {
            // The maximum score for the current box to the end has
            // already been calculated; re-use it.
            return score + cache[i];
        } else if (i == boxes.length - 1) {
            // Last box; go ahead and add it to the score and we're done.
            return score + boxes[i];
        } else {
            /* Now there are three options with at least one more box
             * after this one: */

            // Add the current box and the next box, and then stop
            // (Two consecutive boxes).
            int s1 = score + boxes[i] + boxes[i + 1];

            // Add the current box and skip a box to keep calculating
            // a score
            int s2 = solve(boxes, i + 2, score + boxes[i], cache);

            // Skip the current box and keep calculating
            int s3 = solve(boxes, i + 1, score, cache);
            
            // Now return the largest of the three
            return Math.max(s1, Math.max(s2, s3));
        }
    }
    
    private static int solve(int[] boxes) {
        int[] cache = new int[boxes.length];
        Arrays.fill(cache, -1);
        // Solve from the end - calculate the maximum score of the
        // last N boxes of the array. Then when calculating the score
        // for the N-1th box, that value can be re-used.
        cache[boxes.length - 1] = boxes[boxes.length - 1];
        for (int i = boxes.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            cache[i] = solve(boxes, i, 0, cache);
        }
        return cache[0];
    }

    private static void show(int[] boxes) {
        System.out.println("Input: " + Arrays.toString(boxes));
        System.out.println("Output: " + solve(boxes));
    }

    /** Generate an array of random numbers for testing large inputs */
    private static void show(Random rng, int size) {
        show(rng.ints(1, 21).limit(size).toArray());
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rng = new Random();      
        show(new int[]{1, 4, 2, 10});
        show(new int[]{1, 4, 5, 3});
        show(rng, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: While technically correct, your solution has an exponential runtime and will be infeasible for large input sizes. I added a solution with linear runtime to my answer.

Comment: @tierriminator See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your greedy approach goes in the right direction, however I see a few issues with your current solution.

First off, your program will crash for inputs of size 1, since your first loop will assume that the input has at least size 2.

Next, you don't have a way to refer to previous decisions being made. In `tempMax` you basically store `boxes[i] + boxes[i+1]`, since with every iteration you remove `boxes[i-1]` from `tempMax`.

An approach would be to store three values for every iteration:

- The maximum if we select the current box and not the previous one (`max0`)
- The maximum if we don't select the current box and there are no consecutive selections for previous iterations (`max0`)
- The maximum if we select the current box when the previous box was also selected (`max11`)

**Edit: Added solution**

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Game {
    public static int solution(int[] boxes) {
        int max0 = 0, max1 = 0, max11 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            int max0_new = Math.max(max0, max1);
            int max1_new = max0 + boxes[i];
            int max11_new = Math.max(max11, max1 + boxes[i]);
            max0 = max0_new;
            max1 = max1_new;
            max11 = max11_new;
        }
        return Math.max(max0, Math.max(max1, max11));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solution(new int[]{1, 4, 2, 10}));
        System.out.println(solution(new int[]{1, 4, 5, 3}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why all that code? My solution also runs in _O(n)_ and it is done in three lines: one to convert to list, one to sort the array and one to display the result of the sum. Because of that, it is more readable.

Comment: The problem is not to find the two largest values in the array. The title is misleading here.

Comment: What is the goal then? Your solution and mine output the same results.

Comment: For those examples yes. It is a classic algorithmic problem: Select entries in the array such that the sum over them is maximal. If two consecutive entries are selected no entries with larger indices are allowed to be selected.